# Is it possible to render fonts the same way in openSUSE as in the former version?

Tags: opensuse, fonts

I have installed the new Leap 15.0 XFCE, but the font rendering is completely different and it bothers me a lot. I checked every options and even though they all match, it still displays thicker fonts:

[image: button]

Is is possible to change the rendering in a fashion that it would result something like the one on the left button. I've changed the anti-aliasing settings, hinting, etc., but they didn't help. Can I make the letters thinner somehow?

Comment: You need to `export FREETYPE_PROPERTIES="truetype:interpreter-version=35"`. More info here: https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/subpixel-hinting.html

Comment: This is actulally mentioned in the Release Notes: https://doc.opensuse.org/release-notes/x86_64/openSUSE/Leap/15.0/#sec.desktop.freetype-rendering-38

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help, it looks perfect now!